# Laravel 5.3 - Keep GET values while requesting other GET values

Tags: php, forms, laravel, get, request

How can i keep values i sent from another route to my dashboard? 
This is how dashboard URL looks after a GET request from another route to dashboard:

```
http://localhost:8000/?lat=45.328686399999995&lng=14.446922599999999
```

When something is searched this happens:

```
http://localhost:8000/?ad_search=stackoverflow&ad_sort=recent
```

How can i make it always look like this?:

```
http://localhost:8000/?lat=45.328686399999995&lng=14.446922599999999&ad_search=stackoverflow&ad_sort=recent
```

Comment: Make sure the values you want to preserve are also present in your form that you're submitting via GET. That is, make sure you output your lat/lng values in your form somewhere

Comment: Share code from where url first become url second. I am sure you need to do something tricky here.

Comment: Hi, this is the script that sends lat & lng to dashboard https://codepaste.net/m1fh8o

Comment: Alexey Mezenin's answer is very good ... but if you use these value in all page, you can use session for your work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add these parameters when building URL. For example, when using `url()` helper:

```
{{ url('/', [
       'ad_search' => 'stackoverflow',
       'ad_sort' => 'recent',
       'lat' => request('lat'),
       'lng' => request('lng')
   ]) }}
```

Comment: And if you don't want to repeat yourself all the, time, create another helper method to use instead.